# Make an object Semi-Transparent while Transforming? (to see where to position it)

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I'm working on a plugin to Photobash in the 3d Viewport, and a tricky thing I've come across is positioning the images, since they're imported with full opacity.

Is there possibly an option for the 3D Viewport to make an object semi-transparent while the Transform operator is being undertaken? Preferably without having to mess with automating shaders

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Click here on "Object"

[image]

Choose here a color and set alpha e.g. to 0.5

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]